# Spacing dissapearing when upgrading from Bootstrap 3 to 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been getting into web design lately, and now I need to build a project it Bootstrap. But I need to be able to build projects in both Bootstrap 3 and 4, so I started with 3 and decided upgrade afterward.

This is how it supposed to look, and it looks fine in Bootstrap 3:

[image]

And the padding was fine too:

[image]

But then I upgraded to Bootstrap 4 and this happened:

[image]

I'm fine with the font shift, by what messed up the padding? Firefox shows 0 padding there now.

My HTML:

```
      <head>
    <title>Testing Grounds</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">

    <br>
    <br>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <h2>Create an account with us!</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll share your email with anyone who will pay us so make sure it's your real email</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Make sure this is the same password you use on other sites because your about to send this to our unencrypted servers</small>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">You agree to our Terms Of Service including spam emails*</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label class="spam-email-label">How many spam emails would you like to receive every hour?*</label>
          <br>
            <select name="select:">
              <option>50,000</option>
              <option>100,000</option>
              <option>1,000,000</option>
              <option>As much as you possibly can, I love Spam!</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Unencrypted Personal Data</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<br>
<br>
</body>
```

app.css is very simple and just aligns the text:

```
#content
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: A number of Bootstrap classes changed from 3 to 4. Take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/ for the changes. Specifically the form section.

Comment: I would just suggest removing `jumbotron-fluid` and seeing what happens :)

Comment: @Steve I've checked but I don't see anything that would affect it.

Comment: @EGC That was it! n8win brought this up as well, what changed between 3 and 4 that broke it that bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `.jumbotron-fluid` class

More info here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/

> To make the jumbotron full width, and without rounded corners, add the .jumbotron-fluid modifier class and add a .container or .container-fluid within.

Comment: So they change the reason for using `jumbotron-fluid`?

Comment: @JhonPiper Actually, I can't find any evidence that the jumbotron-fluid class existed in Bootstrap 3. I just confirmed by searching the source of version 3.4.1 for "jumbotron-fluid" - returning no results.

Comment: Your right! The guide I was following claimed to be talking about Bootstrap 3, they must have messed up somewhere along the way. Ether way thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

just put some `padding` in your class, `jumbotron-fluid` takes full width, that's why your layout is messed up,

*Add `p-4` in your `id="content`" and `p-5`' in `jumbtron` class*.
 as you see in the below example

`p` is short form of `padding` in *bootsrtp*.
`p-1,... p-5` you cant put

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Testing Grounds</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <br>
  <br>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content" class="p-2">
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid p-5">
        <h2>Create an account with us!</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll share your email with anyone who will pay us so make sure it's your real email</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Make sure this is the same password you use on other sites because your about to send this to our unencrypted servers</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">You agree to our Terms Of Service including spam emails*</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label class="spam-email-label">How many spam emails would you like to receive every hour?*</label>
            <br>
            <select name="select:">
              <option>50,000</option>
              <option>100,000</option>
              <option>1,000,000</option>
              <option>As much as you possibly can, I love Spam!</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Unencrypted Personal Data</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>
```

Happy codin'!